html script checkbox condition to show specific text
Hi I need help with my code so basically I'm making a project where when you select the checkboxes and it will show a text result. I was able to create a if else condition but I'm getting a problem with ,it is showing all the text if all checkboxes are checked.
here's my code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

<label for="myCheck">Checkbox:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">

<label for="myCheck">Checkbox2:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="text" style="display:none"> both</p>
<p id="text2" style="display:none">ch1!</p>
<p id="text3" style="display:none">ch2!</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  
    /*should only show text "both"*/
  if (checkBox.checked == true && myCheck1.checked == true){
      text.style.display = "block";
    
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
     
  }
 /* show text "ch1"*/
   if (myCheck.checked == true){
  text2.style.display = "block";


     
  } else {
     text2.style.display = "none";
     
  }
  /* show text "ch2"*/
    if (myCheck1.checked == true){
    text3.style.display = "block";
    
  } else {
     text3.style.display = "none";
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>

I tried hiding the other texts by putting  it like this
if (checkBox.checked == true && myCheck1.checked == true){
      text.style.display = "block";
      text2.style.display = "none";
      text3.style.display = "none";


  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";

but it still didn't work I really need help thank you.

Start by hiding all three, then enable them as needed. See the code snippet:


function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");

  text.style.display = "none";
  text2.style.display = "none";
  text3.style.display = "none";

  /*should only show text "both"*/
  if (checkBox.checked == true && myCheck1.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  }
  /* show text "ch1"*/
  else if (myCheck.checked == true){
    text2.style.display = "block";
  }
  /* show text "ch2"*/
  else if (myCheck1.checked == true){
    text3.style.display = "block";
  }
}
      <p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

      <label for="myCheck">Checkbox:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">

      <label for="myCheck">Checkbox2:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" onclick="myFunction()">

      <p id="text" style="display:none"> both</p>
      <p id="text2" style="display:none">ch1!</p>
      <p id="text3" style="display:none">ch2!</p>




thank you so much . very simple solution you saved me ^^

The best answer is provided by @Ray Wallace,my answer is not easy to understand ,you can try it.


<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

    <label for="myCheck">Checkbox:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction(text2,myCheck)">

    <label for="myCheck">Checkbox2:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" onclick="myFunction(text3,myCheck1)">

    <p id="text" style="display:none"> both</p>
    <p id="text2" style="display:none">ch1!</p>
    <p id="text3" style="display:none">ch2!</p>

    <script>
      function myFunction(el, checkbox) {
        if (text.style.display === "block") {
          text.style.display = "none";
          text2.style.display = "block";
          text3.style.display = "block";
        }
        el.style.display = checkbox.checked ? "block" : "none";
        /*should only show text "both"*/
        if (myCheck.checked && myCheck1.checked) {
          text.style.display = "block";
          text2.style.display = "none";
          text3.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    </script>



